# PHP Form Data Sanitization

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Is the `filter_var` function with the parameter `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` an acceptable means to sanitizing database inputs?

I'm using the following when receiving input from a form and wanted to see if this was considered an acceptable practice.

I know that ideally one should use a parameterized interface but I'm curious about alternatives, provided there are any acceptable alternatives, to that approach.

```
$this->fname = filter_var( $this->fname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
```

Comment: To sanitize data going to database. As you are using php. I would recommend you use first PDO prepared statements, which reduces the risk of  the sql injections and  also you need to use client side input data sanitation methods.

Comment: I do have JavaScript validation on the form fields, but I would ideally like to have another layer between the form and the database.

Comment: That seems good to me. For server side when using php. PDO and prepared statements are really good so far and do the job. That should be enough i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first say that you Use PDO, and make your queries safer by using  prepared queries.
[PDO Prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

mysql_real_escape_string. function is good but don't use it with addslashes() function at the same time , they can confict each other.

Comment: I should further specify that we are using a Microsoft SQL Server database.  As such, I just took a look at the PDO documentation on php.net it states that functionality with MS SQL server is "experimental", that's not really desirable in this case.  It looks like PDO handles MySQL quite well, but not necessarily SQL Server.

Comment: I just looked a little bit further at the documentation and it appears that PDO also has `PDO_ODBC` for use with system DSNs.  I think that better addresses what I was initially looking for.  Please disregard my previous statement about PDO and MS SQL Server.

Comment: I was about to write to you about this. PDO is php database abstraction and  is designed not only for Mysql but also all other existing Database Languages. Cheers

Comment: Yeah, I saw PDO_ODBC listed maybe a moment after I clicked "back" from the Microsoft SQL Server section of the docs and felt a little foolish.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say no. It will strip out or encode, depending on the flag you set, non-string characters however it's always a good idea to keep database sanitisation with functions such as [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Plus it's not going to do any harm having the extra layer of security in there.

Comment: That's my understanding of the situation as well but more precisely the problem I'm facing is that we're using an ODBC connection to access a Microsoft SQL Server database.  There is no equivalent function to `mysql_real_escape_string` with ODBC to the best of my knowledge, what's the best method to use under those circumstances?

Comment: This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197828/how-to-sanitize-odbc-database-input) perhaps?