# Zeolibs: Unknown column in Where clause

Tags: sql, database, delphi, where-clause, zeos

I am trying to execute a SQL query using Zeolibs but compiler keeps complaining with the following error - Unknown column in Where clause.

```
ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE TagName = '+theSig.f.TagName;
ZQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

But I checked all the columns in my database table and it is correct as I have it here **TagName**

What is wrong with my SQL statement?

Comment: What's the ZQuery1.SQL.Text value after your assignment?

Comment: @jarlh `'SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE TagName = GB1'#$D#$A`

Comment: that's the problem you have single quote in query??

Comment: The you've lost quotes around your value. Right now it looks for a column with that odd value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [QuotedStr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.QuotedStr) function. So your code will be

```
ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE TagName = '+QuotedStr(theSig.f.TagName);
```

A better alternative is to use [parametrized queries](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries) (this will block attempts for SQL injection - take a quick look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000648/delphi-prevent-against-sql-injection) question).

```
ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE TagName = :myparam';
ZQuery1.ParamByName('myparam').AsString := theSig.f.TagName;
```

Comment: You are right I apparently needed double quotes around the TagName value. I played around with statement and got it to work. `SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE TagName = " '+theSig.f.TagName+' " ';`

Comment: It is better to use parametrized queries instead of lots and lots of quotas.